# How to set the View layout gravity on Xml on android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I Tried to add a bouncing dot loading using this library
com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3

But the view is always in the "left"
[image: But the view is always in the "left"]

This is my xml code

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
            <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                android:id="@+id/here"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
                app:indicatorColor="#FF9800"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Aman i don't think it needs gradle file he just need to set that layout in center of screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work:

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
            <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                android:id="@+id/here"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
                app:indicatorColor="#FF9800"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the entire thing inside a **RelativeLayout** and set

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear Layout or Relative layout whatever convenient to you.

Use add this below line for Linear Layout,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|start"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For Relative Layout just add below code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for this, I think it's better to use **RelativeLayout** with **layout_centerInParent** for child like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
                app:indicatorColor="#FF9800"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**but for LinearLayout**, I think your problem can be solved with set AVLoadingIndicatorView layout **width** and **height** `"wrap_content"` or a const value.